# Kendo TreeView Expand does not work

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

Hi I have Kendo TreeView as follows:

```
<div id="AftermarketTreeView"></div>
$("#AftermarketTreeView").kendoTreeView({
     dataTextField: ["text"],
     select: onSelectAftermarketTreeNodes,
     loadOnDemand: false
});
```

and I have bind this treeView from Controller as follows:

```
   List<OUT_POMONTOCARLODATA> items = new List<OUT_POMONTOCARLODATA>();

                OUT_POMONTOCARLODATA root = new OUT_POMONTOCARLODATA { id = 1, parent = 0,  text = "Initiate" };
                items.Add(root);

                root = new OUT_POMONTOCARLODATA { id = 11, parent = 1,  text = "Parts Selection" };
                items.Add(root);

                root = new OUT_POMONTOCARLODATA { id = 12, parent = 1, text = "Assumptions" };
                items.Add(root);

                root = new OUT_POMONTOCARLODATA { id = 13, parent = 1,  text = "Team" };

 var result = new JsonResult() { Data = items };
 return result;
```

and using Ajax I am binding it

```
$.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
           url: ResolveUrl("/CreateMaintainAnalysis/GetMontoCarloData"),
           data: { AnalysisID: AnalysisID },
           success: function (resultData) {
      $("#AftermarketTreeView").data("kendoTreeView").dataSource.data(Data);

           },
 });
```

and then In JS I want to expand this as follows:

```
var treeview = $("#AftermarketTreeView").data("kendoTreeView");
treeview.expand(treeview.findByText("Initiate"));
```

OR

```
var treeView = $("#AftermarketTreeView").data('kendoTreeView');
 var dataSource = treeView.dataSource;
 var dataItem = dataSource.get(1); // find item with id = 5
 var node = treeView.findByUid(dataItem.uid);
 treeView.expand(node);
```

But both is not working for me.

Comment: Help would be really appreciated !!! I am stucked here

Comment: Your treeView is being rendered and displayed correctly ? It just doesn't expands ?

Comment: Yes Its getting rendered correctly..just i need to expand first node and others to be disabled..on Click event...